# Expressing a polynomial as the sum of powers of another polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> If $F$ is a field and $f$, $g$ in $F[X]$ with $\deg g≥1$, then there exist unique polynomials $f_0, f_1,...,f_r$ in $F[X]$ such that $\deg f_i < \deg g$ for all $i$ and $f=f_0 + f_1g^2+\cdots+ f_rg^r$.

It seems to me that it is related to Euclidean algorithm, but the algorithm states that the degree of the remainder, not that of the quotient is smaller than the degree of $g$,

Comment: So what? These $f_0, f_1,...,f_r$ (all of them) are indeed remainders.

Comment: Could you provide more details, please? It seems to me that $f_i$ is like quotient.

Comment: You can probably recognize the "every natural number has a decimal representation" result. Same proofs. We can obtain the $f_i$ either from the top down or from the bottom up.

Comment: You divide your $f$ by $g$; the remainder is $f_0$. Then you divide the quotient by $g$ again; the remainder is $f_1$. And so on. Indeed, this is akin to building a decimal (or any other base) representation of a number.

Comment: Many thanks! By the way, using induction instead of speaking of the algorithm process may make the proof easier to understand. But the idea is the same.